# Python 2.7 Why wont with open create a new file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am currently trying to create a new file based off of a path that is sent from a server but then I get an error message saying No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\xxxx\\OneDrive\\Downloads\\thing.PDF'

here is my code:

```
        file_path2 =  s.recv(5000)
        file_name2 = s.recv(5000)

        extend = "\\"

        BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
        with open(file_path2 + extend + "new_ " + file_name2, 'wb') as fw:
            msg = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
            fsize = int(msg.decode('utf-8'))
            rsize = 0

            while True:
                data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
                rsize = rsize + len(data)
                fw.write(data)
                if rsize >= fsize:
                    print('Breaking from file write')
                    break
            print("Received..")
```

Comment: Does the directory path up to the file name (i.e., `C:\\Users\\xxxx\\OneDrive\\Downloads`) exist?

Comment: @Mureinik yes it exists